# jQuery simulate onClick once ajax completes

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm simply trying to load up a page that grabs information from the device and send it to an API. On success I need it to direct to the onCLick page1 function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                // load index page when the page loads
               var deviceID = "300"; //for testing purposes
                $.ajax({
                    url: "funcEntity.cfc?method=setSession&returnformat=json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        deviceID: deviceID
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                            // Simulate function to open #page1
                    }
                });
                $("#page1").click(function () {
                    // load home page on click
                    $("#response").html("TESTING 1");
                });
                $("#page2").click(function () {
                    // load about page on click
                    $("#response").html("TESTING 2");
                });
                $("#page3").click(function () {
                    // load contact form onclick
                    $("#response").html("TESTING 3");
                });
                $("#page4").click(function () {
                    // load contact form onclick
                    $("#response").html("TESTING 4");
                });
                $("#page5").click(function () {
                    // load contact form onclick
                    $("#response").html("TESTING 5");
                });
            });
```

I tried `$('#foo').trigger('click');` with no success as well. What am I missing?

Comment: Remember, programatically triggering a click only runs the defined function, not the native behavior

Comment: which element's click event you want to trigger? Are those elements are created dynamicly?

Comment: `$('#page1')[0].click();` ??? But which type of element is `#page1`? Is the success callback at least reached?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi I want it to trigger  `$("#page1").click(function () {});

Comment: @A.Wolff #page1 is a link. Yes, the success callback works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you need all those click events.  I got this to work on my server.

Rather than use all of those click events, why not just assign a class to all related nav buttons, then attach the click event once.   Then you can load pages based on the id attribute.

I think you either need to bind the click event with .on() to those elements, which I did below to all elements with the .nav class, or it somehow has to do with the placement of the ajax code (unlikely).   I moved it below the click events.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="home" class="nav">Home</button>
    <button id="about" class="nav">About Us</button>
    <button id="contact" class="nav">Contact</button>
    <div id="response"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            // bind click event to nav elements
            $('.nav').on('click', function() {
                // get the id
                var page = $(this).attr('id');

                // now you can use the id to load a specific page
                switch(page) {
                  case 'home':
                    $('#response').html('Redirect to Home');
                    break;
                  case 'about':
                    $('#response').html('Redirect to About Us');
                    break;
                  case 'contact':
                    $('#response').html('Redirect to Contact');
                    break;
                }
            });

            // substitute your ajax code here
            $.ajax({
                url: "mycode.php",
                type: "post"
            }).done(function() {
                // trigger home page click
                $('#home').trigger('click');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```